# xCode shows UITableViewCell with key/value pairs in the Variables View

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am creating an App with an usual UITableView with custom UITableViewCells (ex. PieChartCell), in the same way like I have done 100 other times before. But if I take a look at the Variables View of xCode (v.6.1), it shows 0 key/value pairs instead of the properties stored in my cell.

This is the PieChartCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "XYPieChart.h"

@interface PieChartCell : UITableViewCell <NSCopying>


@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet XYPieChart *_vXYPieChart;


@end
```

This is my initialization of the cell in a UITableViewController

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Breakpoint 1: pieCell looks normal (have a look at screenshot 1)
    PieChartCell *pieCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"pieCell"];        

    // Breakpoint 2: pieCell changes to 0 key/value pairs in the Variables View (have a look at screenshot 2)

    // the pieCell is never nil at this point so it isn't be executed
    if (pieCell == nil)
            pieCell = [[PieChartCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"pieCell"];

    // ... further UI initialization ...
    // pieCell haven't got any properties shown in the Variables View or any (0) key/value pairs

    return pieCell;
}
```

Here are the screenshots of my Variables View:

Screenshot 1 (at Breakpoint 1)

[image: VariablesView Screenshot 1]

Screenshot 2 (at Breakpoint 2)

[image: VariablesView Screenshot 2]

I have also tried to initialize the cell in other ways f.ex. without *dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier* but also without success.

I designed the cell in the storyboard (UITableViewCell (alias:PieChartCell), UIView (alias:XYPieChart)) and connected the IBOutlet as well as checked the Identifier "pieCell".

Does someone know why the cell is shown like that and how I can change the Variables View of the cell to the usual one, with properties, etc.?
I know I can debug it with NSLog but I just want to know how to prevent it in the future.

**EDIT:**
By the way, the PieCharCell is the second custom cell I am adding. Maybe that could be the issue, that I am using two different types and sizes of UITableViewCells???

Comment: It may not be anything you're doing.  The variables view has been known to lie.  Use `po pieCell` and compare the results.

Comment: Hmm okay I supposed this answer :/ thanks anyway!

Comment: Have you check whether you have set the Identifier for the second cell as "pieCell" correctly? And also, have you make sure that all other custom cells don't share the same identifier with this one?

Comment: Hi Yuchen! Yes I checked everything multiple times but the variables view is still showing the cell in the same way. However I think I accidentally changed anything in my code, because all cell-objects works now, except for the appearance in the variables view. Maybe Phillip is right and I just have to accept that the variables view is not reliable in some situations.